# SwiftUI Segmented picker inside Navigation Bar and below navigation title

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-layout

What Im trying to achieve is to have a segmented picker inside the navigation bar, but below the title of the navigation bar while still having the collapse animation.
For example instead of the search, I need a segmented picker:

| Uncollapsed | Collapsed |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Large title not collapsed] | [image] |

Comment: For the simplest solution Try toolbar and principal vs navigation title

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like that but it could work.

[image]

[image]

```swift
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("SwiftUI")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    VStack {
                        Picker("", selection: $selectedOption) {
                            ForEach(options, id:\.hashValue) {option in
                                Text(option)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If it doesn't need to collapse you can do this.

```swift
        NavigationView {
             VStack {
                    Picker("", selection: $selectedOption) {
                        ForEach(options, id:\.hashValue) {option in
                            Text(option)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                 .padding(.horizontal)
                 List {
                     ForEach(options, id:\.self) {
                         searchText in Text(searchText)
                     }
                 }
                 .navigationBarTitle(Text("Select"))
             }
         }
```

[image]

Comment: Not really what Im looking for tbh

Comment: Does it need to collapse?

Comment: I want to achieve this translucent look so that you can see the content through the navigation bar